# AVFoundation miniFrameDuration property not available in swift

Tags: swift3, avfoundation

[AVCaptureConnection setVideoMinFrameDuration:] 
just like in obj-C I am unable to find same for swift

For Swift I tried

```
var device = AVCaptureDevice()
    device?.activeVideoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 1);
```

But still no luck in swift

Answer (score 1):

The method you are searching for is `videoMinFrameDuration` from AVCaptureConnection. This function is deprecated since iOS7.

By the way, the documentation say :

> You can only set this value if isVideoMinFrameDurationSupported is true.

You should check that isVideoMinFrameDurationSupported is true

If you want to replace that function please read that answer : [videoMinFrameDuration is Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606778/videominframeduration-is-deprecated)

Source : https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcaptureconnection/1388931-videominframeduration